# To avoid hiding of blinking cursor in contentEditable

Tags: javascript

I am having a div with contentEditable="true" and while clicking outside the div I dont want to hide the blinking cursor. Is there a way to prevent the hiding of blinking cursor

Comment: Then you'll need to listen for blur events on the field, and forcibly reinstate focus to it. Focus is the only way it'll keep blinking.

Comment: Do you mean you want to always keep it focused? Or just keep showing a blinking cursor whether or not it's focused? Both of these seem a bit confusing from a users perspective.

Comment: Just to show the blinking cursor

Comment: That's a really bad idea. User conventions exist for a reason. What sense does it make to make the field look as though it's in focus, and able to receive input, if in fact it doesn't, and it isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cursor blinks when the element is focused, so a quick fix is to never loose focus of the element having `contenteditable: true`.

```js
const et = document.querySelector('div');
let doit = false;
document.querySelector('div[contenteditable=true]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    doit = true;
});
document.querySelector('*').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(et !== document.activeElement && doit) {
        et.focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mimick the blinking cursor:

```js
$("#text").focusout(function() {
  $("#blinker").addClass("blinking");
}).focusin(function () {
  $("#blinker").removeClass("blinking");
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blinking {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: blink 0.6s ease-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="text" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span id="blinker" class="blinking"></span></h1>
```